# GCP log explorer filter for list item count more than 1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, filter, explorer, audit-logging

I am trying to write a filter in GCP log explorer, which can look for a count of the values of an attribute.

Example:
I am trying to find the logs like below, which has two items for "referencedTables" attribute.
[GCP Log Explorer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk7W2.png)

I have tried below options which doesn't work -

> protoPayload.metadata.jobChange.job.jobStats.queryStats.referencedTables.*.count>1

> protoPayload.metadata.jobChange.job.jobStats.queryStats.referencedTables.count>1

Also tried Regex looking for "tables" keyword occurrence twice -

> protoPayload.metadata.jobChange.job.jobStats.queryStats.referencedTable=~"(\tables+::\tables+))"

Also tried Regex querying second item, which means there are more than one items -

> protoPayload.metadata.jobChange.job.jobStats.queryStats.referencedTables[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk7W2.png)=~"^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+$"

Note that - these types of logs are BigQuery audit logs, that are logged in GCP logging service, when you run "insert into.. select" type of queries in BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't use logging filters to filter **across** log entries only **within** a log entry.

One solution to your problem is [log-based metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics) where you'd create a metric by extracting values from logs **but** you'd then have to use [MQL](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql) to query (e.g. count) the metric.

A more simple (albeit ad hoc) solution is to use use [`gcloud logging read`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read) to `--filter` the logs (possibly `--format` the results in JSON for easier processing) and then pipeline the results into a tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) where you could count the results.